# PL/SQL trigger: can't create apex user

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am working on a database and one of the final tasks left is to create user accounts. For some reason I can't seem to get it to work. In fact, none of the commented code works when uncommented. Our primary concern is being able to automate the creation of user accounts rather than creating them manually. I am hoping someone can shed some light into the errors of my ways so my code will compile.

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_Students
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF SRN, Surname, Forename, Username, DOB, Date_Cv_Submitted, Date_cv_approved, same_address, home_phone_no, home_postcode ON Students 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN
   :NEW.SRN := seq_SRN.nextval;

   CREATE USER :new.USERNAME
   IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
   PROFILE app_user
   PASSWORD EXPIRE;

    --IF (ACTIVE_ACCOUNT = 'Y' AND CV_APPROVED = NULL) THEN
    --    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot create an account that is active before the cv is approved!');
    --END IF;        

END IF; 

--IF UPDATING THEN
    --IF (DATE_CV_APPROVED != NULL) THEN
    --:new.Active_Account := 'Y';
    --END IF;
--END IF;

:NEW.forename := INITCAP(:NEW.forename);
:NEW.surname := INITCAP(:NEW.surname);

:NEW.home_postcode := UPPER(:NEW.home_postcode);

:NEW.home_phone_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.home_phone_no, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
:NEW.home_phone_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.home_phone_no,
                   '([[:digit:]]{5})([[:digit:]]{6})', '(\1) \2');


IF :NEW.same_address = 'Y' THEN
:NEW.term_no := :NEW.home_no;
:NEW.term_postcode := :NEW.home_postcode;
:NEW.term_phone_no := :NEW.home_phone_no;
ELSE
:NEW.term_postcode := UPPER(:NEW.term_postcode);
:NEW.term_phone_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.term_phone_no, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
:NEW.term_phone_no := REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.term_phone_no,
                   '([[:digit:]]{5})([[:digit:]]{6})', '(\1) \2');
END IF;


IF (:NEW.DOB + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(18,'YEAR') > SYSDATE) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Client must be at least 18 years of age!');
END IF;

IF (:NEW.Date_cv_approved < :NEW.date_cv_submitted) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot approve a cv before it is submitted!');
END IF; 

END;
```

the error is

> Compilation failed, line 6 (13:19:44) The line numbers associated with
>   compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This
>   only affects the compilation of database triggers. PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: (
>   begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod null
>   pragma raise return select update while with    << continue
>   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql
>   execute commit forall merge pipe purge.

I have changed my method to:

```
   APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER(
   p_user_name => :new.USERNAME,
   P_web_password => 'Password123');
```

and it now produces this error:

> An API call has been prohibited. Contact your administrator. Details
>   about this incident are available via debug id "46046".
>
> Contact your application administrator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems funny that i am answering my own question but i solved the issue. The code i used to create apex users is the following.

```
   APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER(
   p_user_name => :new.USERNAME,
   P_web_password => 'Password123',
   p_change_password_on_first_use => 'Y');
```

The error above was solved by changing the security settings from within the application builder to allow the api to work this is found by the following.
Application Builder -> (Your Application) -> Shared Components -> Security Attributes and finally tick the boxes next to runtime API Usage at the bottom of the page, i ticked all 3 as i needed to.

Comment: Thank you, you probably just saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute create statements directly from PLSQL.

change this to:

```
IF INSERTING THEN
   :NEW.SRN := seq_SRN.nextval;

   execute immediate 'CREATE USER '||:new.USERNAME ||'
                      IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
                      PROFILE app_user
                      PASSWORD EXPIRE';
```

Comment: 1 error has occurred
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger ORA-06512: at "APEX514.TRG_STUDENTS", line 6 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APEX514.TRG_STUDENTS'

Comment: Matt - see latest response about PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to hopefully solve your COMMIT issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your trigger for an autonomous transaction in order to commit within a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT ON your_table FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
...
```

HTH